# How to stop select statement from overwriting the other if they save to the same column

Tags: ruby-on-rails

so I am trying to save one of these select statements depending on another select.  I have both of these select statements hidden and if the previous select option is 1 `goals` is shown.  If 2 is selected the `budget` is shown.  But the problem is when I try to set the next value.  The last select value overwrites the other.  So if I select `goals` and try to save that value the `budget` select will overwrite it.  What is the best way to stop this from happening?

```
<div class="form-group" id="goal_attachid" style="display: none;">
<%= form.label :"Select Goal to Attach" %>
   <select name="post[attachid]" id="goal_attachid">
    <option disabled value="" selected hidden>Please Select</option>
    <% Goal.where(user_id:current_user).each do |goal| %>
       <option value=<%= goal.id %>> Goal: <%= goal.title %></option>
    <% end %>
   </select>
  </div>

    <div class="form-group" id="budget_attachid" style="display: none;">
       <%= form.label :"Select Budget to Attach" %>
       <select name="post[attachid]" id="budget_attachid">
        <option disabled value="" selected hidden>Please Select</option>
        <% Budget.where(user_id:current_user).each do |budget| %>
           <option value=<%= budget.id %>> Budget: <%= budget.month %> <%= budget.year %>
        </option>
       <% end %>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Isn't it extremely obvious that the best way to prevent one param key from overwriting the other is to not name them the exact same thing?

Comment: Also don't use all the version tags. They are not ornaments and won't attract additional attention to your question as nearly nobody follows the `ruby-on-rails-x` tags. Use version tags to specify which version you are using.